# Handle large JSON files in TableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to parse a large JSON file (approx: 1000 rows containg a tuple with 8 strings) and display this in a `UITableView`. What I already have is working but I am looking for a more efficient way of displaying them.

At the moment my code looks likes this:

```
public func GET(request: String, callback: (result: JSON?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string : "SOMEURL")
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!){
         (data, response, error) -> Void in

         if error != nil { 
             callback(result: nil, response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, error: error!)
         } else {
            callback(result: JSON(data : data!), response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, error: nil)
         }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This does parse the data using `SwiftJSON` (see JSON(data : data!)), then when it comes to actually filling an array i use a class containing two attributes (one for the Main text in table and one for detail text)

```
class SomeClass {
    let MainText : String
    let DetailText : String

    init(MainText : String, DetailText : String) {
        self.MainText = MainText
        self.DetailText = Detailtext
    }
}
```

Now in the `UITableView` i have a .swift file and in the

```
override func ViewDidLoad() {
    //code
}
```

I use a loop to get the data from the result callback in the GET method to append to an array of

```
var rows : [SomeClass] = []
```

This is very CPU intensive but I did not find another way to deal with this problem. I tried only displaying 50 rows in the table and only creating 50 class items for the rows. But none of that matters, what I fear is that the `SwiftyJSON` way of dealing with this problem is not the right one but i thought that maybe I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem, you are worried about CPU / Energy Efficiency.

What you should consider, if it's not how your app already works, is implementing the parsing process in the background thread, make your [SomeClass] array observable and update the table when it changes (aka when the background parsing added an new value to it).

So first make your parsing function run in background (for instance with the [Async](https://github.com/duemunk/Async) GCD wrapper) :

```
func callback(JSON?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse, error: NSError?) {
    Async.background {
        //Do your JSON parsing stuff here, XXX is a SomeClass object
        rows <- rows + [XXX]
    }
}
```

You might have noticed the unusual syntax for the array appending method. That's because making your array "observable" is part of the solution. I advise you to get the [Observable-Swift](https://github.com/slazyk/Observable-Swift) library to make it easier to observe.

Once added to your project, change your array declaration :

```
var rows = Observable([SomeClass]())
```

Now implement the method that will be called when your callback parsed a new item (for instance in your `viewDidLoad:`)

```
rows.afterChange += { self.table.reloadData() }
```

where `table` is your table view

If you want to implement a power-friendly runtime, you might want to update the table every time 50 or 100 objects are added to the array. This can be done so (if you want to do so do not implement the method right above):

```
rows.afterChange += { if $1.count / 100 = 1 { self.table.reloadData() }}
```

where 100 is the value of new object required to be added in order to update the table. With Observable-Swift, $0 represents the array before it was updated and $1 the array after its update.

One last thing : the `rows` array is no longer of type `[SomeClass]` but `Observable<SomeClass>`. If you want to access the `[SomeClass]` value, just replace `rows` by `rows.value`

Hope I didn't misunderstood your question. Anyway if I did, I think that can still help providing a better implementation of JSON parsing.

Comment: I think this burden has to be pushed to the backend. Although you are doing something like that, that big trunk of data still sits in memory. Selectively query the data back should be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be worried about how much of data you have to display in TableView. 
TableView class handles everything for you as long as you pass the json object properly as a Tablesource.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a pretty good concern about how you use the resources. Normally, we will go with pagination if you don't want to query back whole amount of data from a request. Then, you will implement some proper logic based on the `skip` and `limit` in order to get further data.

As for the `UITableView`, there is nothing to worry about. Because, it's developed in an efficient way. The total number of cell in memory is the total number of cell visible. The `UITableView` will help populating the data via delegation methods. It's not like: you have 500 rows of data, then it has 500 `UITableViewCell`. It's reusability.